# how to test a css property in selenium using java

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, selenium-rc

I want to test that a certain text present on my page is **BOLD** in appearance. like labels for all mandatory fields are presented in BOLD . I am using java to write my selenium testscripts and execute the tests with selenium RC. The problem is that HTML tab on firebug tells nothing about CSS properties. All CSS properties of an element are listed on the CSS tab of firebug.

Answer (score 2):

If you would have entered your question in google you would have founds lots of answers.

This is one tutorial that will help you:
http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/